# Entity Framework - Not able to add edmx file in MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework, edmx

I am using VS 2015 and created MVC project. Now I have created tons of edmx files with SQL server database but I am facing issue with MySQL database.
At certain point, wizard got disappear and not able to add edmx file to project.

[image: Step 1]

In above picture, after selecting EF Designer from Db, I select connection.

[image: Step2]

then i come to this screen and as i press next button, it just got disappear and nothing is happening.

I dont know if its problem with VS 2015 or something else?

Really need help with this.

Comment: Try (re-)installing both `MySql.Data.dll` and `MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll` references first, because I saw EF 6 option button grayed out in the EF version selection. Also check if the MySQL Connector version matches with the DLL version you're using.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Did it. But nothing is happening new. Problem persist..and even I have tried installing visual studio 2017 too. Same problem is happening in visual studio 2017.